# Why does Gaming SE still have beta logo?

Tags: support, design, beta-phase, specific-site

So I just went to [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) and noticed that their is no new logo like on [WebApps](http://nothingtoinstall.com).

[image: WTF?]

Is this because of the domain name confusion or is their another reason?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me... maybe refresh or hard-refresh your browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a cache issue, just press Ctrl+F5.

Comment: ^this, it happened to me as well. You'll also likely have to reload gaming.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico for the icon to refresh